# Deploying rails application on cpanel WHM on centos 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cpanel

I am deploying a new rails 7 app on cpanel whm OS is centos 7, I am following the following guide.
https://www.thecpaneladmin.com/installing-ruby-on-rails-passenger-cpanel-server/
Points I would like to add:

1. There is no ruby on rails button in cpanel even though enabled from WHM
2. I have tried with the way in which we have to register application but It doesn't work

Currently I have created a new project inside public_html according to link the I mentioned earlier and did the configurations according to it but if I try mydomain.com It open index.html file inside public_html

Comment: maybe this link help you: https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/software/ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use passenger gem inside the project that is to be deployed
Passenger Documentation for details: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/apache/oss/el7/deploy_app.html#rails_install-app-dependencies